# one line ruby array creation and population

Tags: ruby, arrays

This is fairly trivial, but it bothers me to no end that I haven't yet found the answer using Google or this forum.  But how can i turn this into one line?  Without have to declare rooms an array above?

```
rooms = []
hwdata.availability.each {|room| rooms << room.name}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
rooms = hwdata.availability.collect {|room| room.name}
```

Or in Ruby 1.9, even more concise:

```
rooms = hwdata.availability.collect &:name
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use #map also.

rooms = hwdata.availability.map {|room| room.name}

Comment: Further info: `map` is just another name for `collect`. So you really can use either.